# How could I go about opening a serial console and sending/recieving data with Arduino board?

Tags: vb.net, arduino, serial-port, usb, communication

I'm working on a program in VB.NET which is a graphical frontend to an Arduino that controls alarm equipment. I figured that it would be simpler to send single bytes to the Arduino in order to run commands (button presses), rather than send strings (which would be more complicated to read on the Arduino and not necessary), over serial. I will have the Arduino print lines with `println("string");` onto the serial console, and repeat those lines into RichTextBox `outputPanel`, appending lines one by one as they come in (and parsing in `Environment.newline`s as needed) exactly as the Arduino sent them.

My problem is that I don't have any experience with serial communications within VB.NET. I am hoping someone can show me how I could set the code up to receive and send such information through VB (I can then reverse engineer it and modify it if needed later).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: thanks, I wasn't able to find that before.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/how-to-receive-strings-from-serial-ports The whole first text block is irrelevant for your question. Please have have some empathy, and keep it short and relevant.